# Angular destroy directive manually

Tags: javascript, angular

There is a way to remove directive manually? For example, I want to do some work only once and remove the directive, so it won't stay in memory.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[doSomething]'
})
export class DoSomethingDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    // do something with the element and destroy the directive
  }

}
```

Comment: It's parent's responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.

**Why**

First of all I don't think you can clear a link to the directive instance from Angular's side.

Secondly, let's count the sheeps.

1. If you don't have any property on the directive object and do not subscribe to anything in the constructor then every directive represents an empty object (after the constructor has finished its execution). All the local variables will be cleared by the garbage collector.
2. If the garbage collector could not remove stuff from point 1 it is totally irrelevant whether you remove the directive link from Angular's scope because the thing will anyway remain in the memory.
3. After the points 1 and 2 it is clear that the only thing which is left after the execution is a link from Angular's engine to the empty object.

Finally, the conclusion:

as long as every directive instance is an empty object which is bound as 1 to 1 to the HTML element (which is a bunch of data including the runtime rendering, CSS rules etc), it is highly probable that you will face the issues with the amount of HTML elements so much way before than you will face the memory problems that it does not even worth thinking on clearing those directive. In addition to the fact that it is not that possible to do, of course.

Comment: The directive class is still in memory, it's not GC.

Comment: "it is highly probable that you will face the issues with the amount of HTML elements so much way before then you will face the memory problems that", what do u mean?

Comment: The class itself is nothing because it will be always existing in the amount of 1. The empty object of this class is just an object with reference to the class as a prototype (That's simplified but enough from the memory prospective).

Comment: If you try to predict how much you will save with this directive removal you will get meaningful numbers only in cases when it will be impossible for the browser to render all those html elements. That's what I mean :)